# DLP build plate adhesion

Tags: adhesion, resin, dlp

Does anyone have tips on improving build plate adhesion in DLP printers? I've heard a thin layer of resin or UV glue applied to the plate will help, but we're not sure if we leave the resin/glue wet, or cure it before we start the print. Apologies for the ignorance here, but I'm just trying to avoid gluing my build plate to the bottom of the resin vat! Any advice would be appreciated.

***Update***
I had a product called ProtoGlass recommended to me in another forum, that apparently works as a good build plate primer for the resin we're trying to grow (BlueCast x5). Ordering today, and I'll update further with the results.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: How about roughening the plate (with very fine grit) so as to produce more surface area "grab"?   I do not know whether this leads to other problems.

Comment: The plate on this machine (B9 Core) has a black coating (maybe anodizing, but not entirely sure). They warn against scratching the surface.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use any glue or any other adhesion modifier to increase your build plate adhesion.
Take these steps instead:

1. Make sure your **build plate is level**
2. Use proper attachment layer (**raft**) - see [3D printing raft in resin 3D printing: what you need to know](https://ameralabs.com/blog/attachment-layer-need-know/).
3. Increase **bottom layer exposure**
4. Make sure your **resin is not cold** (25+ °C works best)
5. Make sure your **build plate is flat and even**. Sometimes they come faulty from the factory. Lay it flat on the glass and see if all corners touch it evenly.
6. **Sand your build plate**
7. Make sure to use high **quality FEP**. If it get's scratched or cloudy - change it.
8. Make sure the **tension of your FEP** is right. Not too tight, not too
   loose.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard that adding a few pieces of masking tape to the print surface improves adhesion.

Comment: DLP printers are resin based. You can not add tape in that application.

Comment: You can still use the masking tape though. I've done it on a DLP printer before.